# Using a big brace over multiple lines - multiple lines left of it

Tags: math-mode, equations, arrays, braces

I am super helpless, I wanna do the following:

Mathmode, 2 lines on the left, a brace over both (using array) and than I wanna have 3 lines on the right. A small example:

```
\begin{align*}
\left.
\begin{array}{l l}
&H_0 : \theta  \in \theta_0\\
&H_1: \theta \in \theta_1 \end{array}
 \right \rbrace 
 \theta \in \Theta \theta_1 \cup \theta_0 = \Theta \\
 \theta_1 \cap \theta_0 = \empty 
\end{align*}
```

Whereever there is only a spaceholder `\` i rather wish a new line. 
Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 12):

The [mathtools](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package provides an environment called `rcases`; it behaves pretty much like the `cases` environment of the `amsmath` package does except that the curly brace is set at the right-hand end.

The following code uses both an `rcases` and an `array` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % mathtools loads the amsmath package automatically
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{rcases}
H_0: & \theta =\theta_0 \in \Theta_0\\
H_1: & \theta =\theta_1 \in \Theta_1 
\end{rcases}
\quad
\begin{array}{r@{\;}l} % make space to RHS of \in and = symbols equal to that used for mathrel items
 \theta \in &\Theta  \\
 \Theta_0 \cup \Theta_1 = &\Theta \\
 \Theta_0 \cap \Theta_1 = &\emptyset
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: A side remark: The third upvote given to this answer put my TeX.SE point total over the 50K mark. Many thanks! TeX.SE is a great place!!

Comment: Thank you very much. But I should have mentioned, that I do not need a second brace (taking together all the three things on the right.) Gonna try to modify it soon.

Comment: @Maria - Thanks for clarifying your typesetting needs; I'll post a modified answer soon.

Comment: @Mico Congratulations! Your contributions are always very valuable!

Answer (score 7):

Here's something to start with:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \left.
  \begin{array}{r@{}l}
    H_0 & {}: \theta \in \theta_0 \\
    H_1 & {}: \theta \in \theta_1
  \end{array}
  \right\rbrace ? \left\lbrace
  \begin{array}{r@{}l}
    \theta & {} \in \Theta \\
    \theta_1 \cup \theta_0 & {}= \Theta \\
    \theta_1 \cap \theta_0 & {}= \emptyset
  \end{array}
  \right.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

You can just use another `array` on the right, which will be centred vertically by default.

If you wish to remove the gaps between the brace and the `array`, use a column specification `r@{}l@{}` (for the left, or `@{}r@{}l` for the right). You don't need the brace on the right-hand, of course. I just wanted to show that it can be done.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using features of the `stackengine` and `scalerel` packages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}[2013-09-11]
\usepackage{scalerel}
\begin{document}
\stackMath\def\stackalignment{l}\def\stacktype{L}
\[
\scaleleftright[1.7ex]{.}
{\stackanchor{H_0: \theta  \in \theta_0}{H_1: \theta \in \theta_1}}
{\}}
\scaleleftright[1.7ex]{\{}
{\stackunder{\stackon{\theta_1 \cup \theta_0 = \Theta}%
                     {\theta \in \Theta}}%
                     {\theta_1 \cap \theta_0 = \emptyset}}
{.}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternately, if you didn't want the right brace,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}[2013-09-11]
\usepackage{scalerel}
\begin{document}
\stackMath\def\stackalignment{l}\def\stacktype{L}
\[
\scaleleftright[1.7ex]{.}
{\stackanchor{H_0: \theta  \in \theta_0}{H_1: \theta \in \theta_1}}
{\}}
\qquad
\stackunder{\stackon{\theta_1 \cup \theta_0 = \Theta}%
                     {\theta \in \Theta}}%
                     {\theta_1 \cap \theta_0 = \emptyset}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]